# Why does my freestyle cycles render appear all black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

Alright so I've been trying to play with compositing and adding a freestyle layer on top.
I realized the render came out all black and it turns out rendering freestyle in cycles gives me an all black render.
I've tried to do the render in eevee, that works, but I desperately need cycles for this one and I can't figure the problem out.
If anyone has the slightest idea I'd be very thankful.
Thank you

Comment: Please uplod your file or a picture from the compositing setup.

Comment: Had to set the background to transparent and rearrenge some nodes, thanks anyways ^^